# Bigquery Data Transfer successful but destination table is empty or missing records

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, copy, data-transfer

I'm trying to copy a table from one project to another using data transfer - dataset copy. On destination either I get an empty table or I get only few records from source table. Both cases show on different tables.

I'm a bit frustrated because the data transfer shows a successful status.

I have also tried bq copy commands, but I get the same issue.

Comment: I appreciate your frustration, but I am not sure your question can be answered meaningfully here at this moment, as it lacks context and details - code, exceptions, results, table comparison results, logs, etc.

Comment: try cloud logging to check any issues also find the jobs in information schema